# Literal tabs in textarea

Tags: script

Allows one to use the tab key on StackOverflow, Codereview.SE, and Programmers.SE in the editbox.

### Installation

- [Click here to install](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/literaltab.user.js). Will only work in Chrome or Firefox (the latter requires Greasemonkey).
- [Source](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/literaltab.user.js)

### Usage

Hit tab in an edit box. Instead of defocusing, the literal ta will be inserted into the textarea.